# How to PowerExpand a generic Product?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, products

I have:

```
PowerExpand[Log[Product[f[i], {i, 1, n}]]] // InputForm
(* Output: Log[Product[f[i], {i, 1, n}]] *)
```

However, I would expect to get the following as the output instead: `Sum[Log[f[i]], {i,1,n}]`

Is it possible to tweak the code somehow to achieve such behavior?

Comment: I think you only can introduce a rule like this: `rule = Log[Product[f_[i], {i, 1, n_}]] :> Sum[Log[f[i]], {i, 1, n}]` and apply it to such expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amplifying @AlexeiBoulbitch 's comment: you may have to implement this transformation manually, as it makes a lot of assumptions.

```
A = Log[Product[f[i], {i, 1, n}]]
```

> $$
> \log \left(\prod_{i=1}^n f(i)\right)
> $$

```
A /. Log[Product[a_, b_]] :> Sum[Log[a], b]
```

> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n \log(f(i))
> $$